# mysterious warning in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.inc.php';  
include 'header.inc.php';


$mesiace  = array("Január", "Február", "Marec", "Apríl", "Máj", "Jún", "Júl",     
"August", "September", "Október", "November", "December");

echo '<div id="rozpis">';
$sql = "SELECT game_id, rival_id, result, h_a, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datum) AS datum FROM        game ORDER BY datum ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
echo '<table>';
echo   '<tr><td>Dátum</td><td>Domáci</td><td>Hostia</td><td>Výsledok</td></tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //here is the problem
{
extract($row);
$prikaz = 'SELECT rival_id, name FROM rival WHERE rival_id = '. $rival_id;
$vystup = mysql_query($prikaz, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$rival = mysql_fetch_array($vystup);
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' .date("j. F Y", $datum). '</td>';
if ($h_a == 1)
{
echo '<td> Capitals </td>';
echo '<td>' .$rival['name']. '</td>';
}
else 
{
echo '<td>' .$rival['name']. '</td>';
echo '<td> Capitals </td>';
}
echo '<td><a href="zapas.php?zapas='. $game_id.'">' .$result. '</td>';
echo '</tr>';  
}
echo '</table>';
}
else
echo 'No matches';

echo '</div>';

include 'zahlavie.php';
?>
```

When I run this script it writes this warning:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
string given in H:\xampp\htdocs\rozpis.php on line 16
```

I really don't know where is problem. In the table I have three rows, but it writes only the first one and then this message. When I run `$query` in phpMyAdmin it runs correctly or when I use `echo mysql_num_rows($result)` it returns correctly also.

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: What is `$db`? Is is the name of your database, or the result of running `mysql_connect`?

Comment: @GlitchMr: It surprises you that someone is asking a question on PHP's `mysql` module? Sure, mysqli and PDO are considered better, but it's not like it's uncommon to use the original `mysql` module...

Comment: @Travesty3 - for old development yes, but many people use legacy modules because they don't know what is best to use. No harm in letting them know!

Comment: I'd also recommend indenting your code a little better.

Comment: @halfer: Fine, then let them know about the better alternatives. But to act shocked that someone is still using a module that is still quite commonly used just seems kinda unnecessarily rude to me.

Comment: I guess it depends how it is interpreted `:)`. I agree S/O could sometimes be a little less spiky towards beginners, but I thought that one was okay (for avoidance of doubt: it was another poster, not me).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the function `extract` and one of your db columns is named "result". Thus is will overwrite the variable $result with some string, which is of course wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT game_id, rival_id, result, h_a, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datum) AS datum FROM        game ORDER BY datum ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row); // <- here is the problem
```

Comment: Yikes, I'd not come across that function before. I will remember never to use it! `;-)`

Comment: +1: excellent spot. A quick solution would be to use `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` to prefix the fields with something.